# Group data by name, count it and make a pie chart

Tags: python, pandas

> Hello. I need to group data by name, count it and make a pie chart of the percentage share of place names from a given among all names.

Link to my excel file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gw5mcu3mJXH0Gg4Q-PnRrxDMFq-6VvDo/view?usp=sharing

```
import pandas as pd                              
import xlrd                                      
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                  

data = pd.read_excel("table.xlsx", sheet_name=0)

data.groupby('Woj.')['Nazwa miejscowości'].unique().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide a small set of sample data as text that we can copy and paste. Include the corresponding desired result. Check out the guide on [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/3620003).

Comment: We do not have your excel file.

Comment: @timgeb https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gw5mcu3mJXH0Gg4Q-PnRrxDMFq-6VvDo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi! so you want one pie chart for each name showing the percentage of places?

Comment: @DavideBrex Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is what you asked, please let me know in case. First I grouped by the names, and then the pie chart shows the amount of places per each name.

```
data.groupby("Woj.")["Nazwa miejscowości"].count().plot.pie(figsize=(10,10),autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes something like this and it has to shows data in %