# pyplot pie chart incorrect values

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I want to plot a pie chart from an categorical variable.
I tried the following ways:

#example df

```
data = {'Category':  ['waschen','anziehen','lesen', 'waschen', 'waschen', 'lesen', 'lesen'],
        'T1': ['1', '2', '3','3', '5', '6', '7']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#change dtype, doesn't work without

```
df.loc[:, 'T1']=df.loc[:, 'T1'].astype('int64')
```

1st try

```
df.groupby(by=['Category']).sum().plot.pie(y='T1', autopct='%2f');
```

pie chart is showing the wrong values, for "lesen" und "waschen" there must be the same value

2nd try

```
df.groupby('Category').count().plot.pie(y='T1', ax=ax, autopct='%2f')
```

only shows the following text: AxesSubplot:ylabel='T1'

I'm beginner with python and searched the last hours for a solution. Has anybody an idea?

[image: pie1]

Comment: It's plotting the image I have uploaded (I hope you can see it?). I want was Python to show with count() how often each of the three categories occur. I'm sorry, I'm sure it is a "beginner problem".

Comment: Not at all. But thank you.

Comment: `values=df['Category'].value_counts()`, `plt.pie(values, autopct= lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x*values.sum()/100))`, `plt.show()`

Comment: But I found this right now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62265209/group-data-by-name-count-it-and-make-a-pie-chart 
That seems to answer my question.

Comment: Do you want percentages, or counts?

Comment: Both is fine. All I want that they are correct. I would try your last suggestion. Thx.